# How to destroy a bi-directional has_one association from either end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here are my models:

```
class Left < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :right, through: :middle
end

class Middle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :left, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :right, dependent: :destroy
end

class Right < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :left, through: :middle
end
```

I would like `left.destroy` to also destroy its `middle` and its `right`.  Similarly I would like `right.destroy` to destroy its `middle` and its `left`.

With the setup above, `right.destroy` does what I want but `left.destroy` does not destroy its `right`.

However if I reverse the order of `Middle`'s `belongs_to` declarations, `right.destroy` stops working and `left.destroy` starts working.

How can I get a left-middle-right association to be destroyed from either end?

Comment: I have a feeling this is a blocking issue. In your first example `left.destroy` tries `left.before_destroy` -> destroy middle -> `middle.after_destroy` -> destroy left-> destroy right. While I have not tracked this all the way through I think what you are seeing is "`middle.after_destroy` -> destroy left" actually halts the chain and then reverts back to `left.destroy` (originally called).

Comment: That was my intuition too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure looks like a bug. Best I could figure is this rollback breaks the chain:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb#L12*

```rb
case options[:dependent]
  when :destroy
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless target.destroy
```

Everything works fine from both directions, if that rollback isn't raised, which is why having your own callbacks works:

```rb
class Middle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :left
  belongs_to :right

  after_destroy -> { left.destroy }
  after_destroy -> { right.destroy }
end
```

---

In case you want to try and patch the bug, here's my one attempt:

```
$ git diff
  diff --git a/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb b/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb
  index 29c72d1024..6e9c68b747 100644
  --- a/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb
  +++ b/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb
  @@ -418,7 +418,7 @@ module ClassMethods
   
       def destroy # :nodoc:
         @_destroy_callback_already_called ||= false
  -      return if @_destroy_callback_already_called
  +      return true if @_destroy_callback_already_called
         @_destroy_callback_already_called = true
         _run_destroy_callbacks { super }
       rescue RecordNotDestroyed => e
```

I only ran activerecord sqlite tests:

```
bundle exec rake test:sqlite3

Finished in 155.701590s, 55.8568 runs/s, 189.7026 assertions/s.
8697 runs, 29537 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 33 skips
```

Comment: Thanks for the patch.  I submitted it to Rails (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/50948) but I wasn't sure of the best way to credit you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: in `Middle`, remove the `:dependent` options from the `belongs_to` declarations and add an `after_destroy` callback which explicitly destroys the `left` and `right` associated objects.

```
class Middle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :left
  belongs_to :right

  after_destroy :destroy_associated

  def destroy_associated
    left.destroy
    right.destroy
  end
end
```

I don't know if this is the canonical way to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

According to ActiveRecord documentation [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3A%3AAssociations%3A%3AClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy?:%7E:text=Note%20that%20%3Adependent,%3Athrough%20associations.), it says:

> Note that :dependent is implemented using Rails’ callback system,
> which works by processing callbacks in order. Therefore, other
> callbacks declared either before or after the :dependent option can
> affect what it does.

So, since we declared `belongs_to :right, dependent: :destroy` at the end of the model, it processes other callbacks which declared before this one. But for the left, it does not process the post callbacks.

In this situation, I think creating `after_destroy` method is the best way to handle the problem.